# DoesNotExist at /rooms/create_room/ Room matching query does not exist (showing error in different function than the one im executing)

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

```
DoesNotExist at /rooms/create_room/
Room matching query does not exist
```

error showing in this line which is a different view function(which is working perfectly) than the one I'm executing in the current template

```
room = Room.objects.get(slug=slug)
```

The indicated function

```
@login_required
def room(request, slug):
    room = Room.objects.get(slug=slug)
    messages = Message.objects.filter(room=room) [0:25]
    return render(request, 'rooms/room.html', {'room': room, 'messages': messages})
```

The function I'm trying to execute for creating room model instance

```
def room_form(request, id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        cf = RoomForm(request.POST or None)
        if cf.is_valid():
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            room = Room.objects.create(room = room, user = request.user, name = name)
            room.save()
            return redirect(room.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            cf = RoomForm()
        context ={
            'room_form':cf,
        }
        return render(request, 'rooms/create_room.html', context)
```

My model.py

```
class Room(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True,blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    # slug = models.SlugField(max_length= 300,null=True, blank = True, unique=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name  + "  |  " + self.user.username
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name + self.created.day)
        super(Room,self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

In my forms

```
class RoomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Room
        fields = [
            'name',
        ]
        labels = {
            "name": "Room Name",
        }
```

In my URLs

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.rooms, name='rooms'),
    path('<slug:slug>/',views.room, name='room'),
    path('create_room/',views.room_form,name="create_room"),
]
```

Im on a deadline and this weird error appeared while creating the create view function. Please help me out here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.rooms, name='rooms'),
    path('<slug:slug>/',views.room, name='room'),
    path('create_room/',views.room_form,name="create_room"),
]
```

Django is going from top to bottom here. Path `rooms/create_room` fits `path('<slug:slug>/',views.room, name='room'),` and there it is trying to work, but you have no `Room` with `create_room` slug I suppose, right? Put `create_room` view above the `room` view and it's going to work better.

But, in advance, your `room_form` view is not going to work anyway. You are calling `room` variable without setting it before.